# How to create a PySpark Dataframe Column which iterates through a circular list

Tags: python, pyspark, circular-list

How can I add a column onto this Pyspark dataframe that loops through a circular list like so:

```
   df = sc.parallelize([['2019-08-29 01:00:00'],
                              ['2019-08-29 02:00:00'],
                              ['2019-08-29 03:00:00'],
                              ['2019-08-29 04:00:00'],
                              ['2019-08-29 05:00:00'],
                              ['2019-08-29 06:00:00'],
                              ['2019-08-29 07:00:00'],
                              ['2019-08-29 08:00:00'],
                              ['2019-08-29 09:00:00'],
                              ['2019-08-29 10:00:00']]).toDF(['DATETIME']).withColumn('DATETIME',col('DATETIME').cast('timestamp'))
```

Desired outcome:

```
+-------------------+---+
|           DATETIME|NUM|
+-------------------+---+
|2019-08-29 01:00:00|  1|
|2019-08-29 02:00:00|  2|
|2019-08-29 03:00:00|  3|
|2019-08-29 04:00:00|  4|
|2019-08-29 05:00:00|  1|
|2019-08-29 06:00:00|  2|
|2019-08-29 07:00:00|  3|
|2019-08-29 08:00:00|  4|
|2019-08-29 09:00:00|  1|
|2019-08-29 10:00:00|  2|
+-------------------+---+
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **row_number** to generate **id** and then use **modulus operator (%)** to get the rotating ids:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.orderBy("DATETIME")

df
.withColumn("id", f.row_number().over(w))
.withColumn("NUM", (col("id") % 4) + 1)
.drop("id")
.show(100, False)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+---+
|DATETIME           |NUM|
+-------------------+---+
|2019-08-29 01:00:00|2  |
|2019-08-29 02:00:00|3  |
|2019-08-29 03:00:00|4  |
|2019-08-29 04:00:00|1  |
|2019-08-29 05:00:00|2  |
|2019-08-29 06:00:00|3  |
|2019-08-29 07:00:00|4  |
|2019-08-29 08:00:00|1  |
|2019-08-29 09:00:00|2  |
|2019-08-29 10:00:00|3  |
|2019-08-29 11:00:00|4  |
|2019-08-29 12:00:00|1  |
|2019-08-29 13:00:00|2  |
|2019-08-29 14:00:00|3  |
|2019-08-29 15:00:00|4  |
|2019-08-29 16:00:00|1  |
|2019-08-29 17:00:00|2  |
|2019-08-29 18:00:00|3  |
|2019-08-29 19:00:00|4  |
|2019-08-29 20:00:00|1  |
|2019-08-29 21:00:00|2  |
|2019-08-29 22:00:00|3  |
|2019-08-29 23:00:00|4  |
|2019-08-30 00:00:00|1  |
|2019-08-30 01:00:00|2  |
|2019-08-30 02:00:00|3  |
|2019-08-30 03:00:00|4  |
|2019-08-30 04:00:00|1  |
+-------------------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I used reduce function to work over original dataframe (this is a *copypastable* example):

```
from functools import reduce

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

sc = SparkContext(__file__)
step = 4  # rows qty

df = sc.parallelize([['2019-08-29 01:00:00'],
                    ['2019-08-29 02:00:00'],
                    ['2019-08-29 03:00:00'],
                    ['2019-08-29 04:00:00'],
                    ['2019-08-29 05:00:00'],
                    ['2019-08-29 06:00:00'],
                    ['2019-08-29 07:00:00'],
                    ['2019-08-29 08:00:00'],
                    ['2019-08-29 09:00:00'],
                    ['2019-08-29 10:00:00']])\
        .toDF(['DATETIME'])\
        .withColumn('DATETIME',col('DATETIME')\
        .cast('timestamp'))

df = df.withColumn('tmp_num', row_number().over(Window.orderBy('DATETIME')))
df = df.withColumn('num', lit('A'))  # temporal random value
rows = df.count()
idxs = list(range(1, rows, step))

# Logic is here
def operate_df(df_, idx):
    return df_.select(df_.DATETIME,
                      df_.num,
                      df_.tmp_num,
                      df_.tmp_num.between(idx, (idx + step - 1)).alias('block')
                      ).withColumn('num', when(col('block') == True, 
                                               row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('block').orderBy('block')))
                                               .otherwise(col('num')))

result_df = reduce(operate_df, idxs, df)
result_df = result_df.drop('tmp_num', 'block')  # drop auxiliar columns
print(result_df.show())
```

This gives me this output:

```
+-------------------+---+
|           DATETIME|num|
+-------------------+---+
|2019-08-29 01:00:00|  1|
|2019-08-29 02:00:00|  2|
|2019-08-29 03:00:00|  3|
|2019-08-29 04:00:00|  4|
|2019-08-29 05:00:00|  1|
|2019-08-29 06:00:00|  2|
|2019-08-29 07:00:00|  3|
|2019-08-29 08:00:00|  4|
|2019-08-29 09:00:00|  1|
|2019-08-29 10:00:00|  2|
+-------------------+---+
```